# siunitx table decimal places in uncertainty

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have a table, where values in the second column (B) are expressed as the mean, with the standard deviation in parentheses next to it, in the same column:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1]S[table-format=4(3.1)]} 
\hline
{A} & {B} \\
\hline
1 & 1176(156.7) \\
2 & 150(20.1) \\
3 & 456(11.1) \\
3 & 24(52.1) \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

When I run this I get: `Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '4(3.1)'.`

When I change it to `table-format=4(3)`, I get: `Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '1176(156.7)'.`

When I change the first row to `1176(156)`, this value prints as expected, but I need the decimal.

When I change the first row to `1176.0(156.1)`, it is printed as "1176.0(1561)", which is not what I want.

How can I print the mean value as an integer, and the standard deviation in parentheses with the first decimal place?

I am using siunitx 2021-07-26 v3.0.23

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Hmm, something is not quite right here, as the updated code is supposed to allow `.` in the uncertainty part. It works if you have a decimal to your numbers, so I guess I need to track down where I've made a mistake.

Comment: Hi @JosephWright , really appreciate your work on siunitx. Great to see you all over various questions during my research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in `siunitx`, to be fixed in v3.0.24. For the present, try

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__siunitx_number_parse_uncert_marker:nNw
  #1#2#3 \q_recursion_tail \q_recursion_stop
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \tl_count:n {#3} - 1 } = { \tl_count:n {#1} }
      {
        \str_if_eq:eeTF
          { \exp_not:V \l__siunitx_number_partial_tl }
          { \prg_replicate:nn { \tl_count:N \l__siunitx_number_partial_tl } { 0 } }
          {
            \__siunitx_number_parse_uncert:NNNN
              #2 \c_false_bool
          }
          {
            \__siunitx_number_parse_uncert:NNNN
              #2 \c_true_bool
          }
            \__siunitx_number_parse_uncert_auxii:NN
      }
      { \exp_after:wN \__siunitx_number_parse_uncert_marker_auxii:nnnN #2 #2 }
    #3 \q_recursion_tail \q_recursion_stop
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__siunitx_number_parse_uncert_marker_auxii:nnnN #1#2#3#4
  {
    \tl_set:Nn #4 { {#1} {#2} { #3 0 } }
    \__siunitx_number_parse_uncert:NNNN #4 \c_true_bool
      \__siunitx_number_parse_uncert_auxii:NN
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Logged as https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/522 and fixed for release later this week

Comment: This still doesn't do what I expect. `1176(156.7)` renders as "1176.0(1567)" when `table-format=4(3.1)`, but I want simply "1176(156.7)", aligned on the decimals. Am I misunderstanding how siunitx parses uncertainty values?

Comment: @JohnL.Godlee Partly yes :) An uncertainty of `156.7` means we must have a decimal value in the main part (`1176.0` no `1176`), otherwise something doesn't make sense. If you want to print the decimal in the uncertainty part, you'll need `uncertainty-mode = compact-marker`.

Comment: (Well, of course, I'd say that if the uncertainty is coming out as `156.7` then actually we've `1200(160)`, as the other digits have no real meaning.)

Comment: @JohnL.Godlee Of course, I'm not actually trying to dictate how you present anything :) My point was that the format understood by `siunitx` starts from the idea that the decimal digits in the 'main' and 'uncertainty' parts will be the same, which makes life a lot easier when converting between `123.4(5)` and `123.4 \pm 0.5` formats.

Comment: I think the format you are after likely fits into my idea that I need multiple uncertainty formats: using it for an s.d. that can go 'beyond' the digits of the main value doesn't fit with the default format used by `siuinitx`. See https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/24.

Answer (score 3):

In the jargon of the `siunitx` package, numbers in parentheses are taken to be the uncertainty components -- and definitely not the standard deviations. For the material at hand, it looks like it would be best to display the standard deviations in a column separate from the means, to label the column headers accordingly, and to drop the parentheses around the std.dev terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}   % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{booktabs}  % replacements for "\hline"

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{Descriptive statistics\strut} % provide a suitable caption
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l S[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=3.1] } 
\toprule
Variable & {Mean} & {Std.Dev}\\
\midrule
1 & 1176 & 156.7 \\
2 & 150 & 20.1 \\
3 & 456 & 11.1 \\
4 & 24 & 52.1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking advice from @Mico I have opted to put the standard deviation in a separate column. However, to maintain the styling I want, I have done the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1] S[table-format=4.0] @{(} S[table-format=3.1] @{)}} 
\hline
{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} \\
\hline
1 & 1176 & 156.7 \\
2 & 150 & 20.1 \\
3 & 456 & 11.1 \\
3 & 24 & 52.1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: table with multicolumn and parentheses]

`@{(}` replaces the default space between columns with a `(`.